# Can anyone explain me StandardScaler?

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn, scaling, standardized

I am unable to understand the [page](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.preprocessing.StandardScaler.html#sklearn.preprocessing.StandardScaler) of the `StandardScaler` in the documentation of `sklearn`.

Can anyone explain this to me in simple terms?

Answer (score 144, accepted):

The idea behind `StandardScaler` is that it will transform your data such that its distribution will have a mean value 0 and standard deviation of 1.
In case of multivariate data, this is done feature-wise (in other words independently for each column of the data).
Given the distribution of the data, each value in the dataset will have the mean value subtracted, and then divided by the standard deviation of the whole dataset (or feature in the multivariate case).

Comment: I find that this answer is not correct. `each value in the dataset will have the sample mean value subtracted`-- this is not true. The mean of EACH feature/column will be subtracted from the values of the specific column. This is done column-wise. There is no `sample mean value subtracted` - See my answer below

Comment: @makis I edited my answer following the clarification you suggest.

Answer (score 182):

## **Intro**

I assume that you have a matrix `X` where each **row/line** is a **sample/observation** and each **column** is a **variable/feature** (this is the expected input for any `sklearn` ML function by the way -- `X.shape` should be `[number_of_samples, number_of_features]`).

---

## **Core of method**

The main idea is to **normalize/standardize** i.e. `μ = 0` and `σ = 1` your features/variables/columns of `X`, *individually*,  **before** applying any machine learning model.

> **`StandardScaler()`** will **normalize the features** i.e. each
> **column** of X, **INDIVIDUALLY**, so that each column/feature/variable will have `μ = 0` and `σ = 1`.

---

**P.S:** I find the most upvoted answer on this page, wrong.
I am quoting "each value in the dataset will have the sample mean value subtracted" -- This is neither true nor correct.

---

See also: [How and why to Standardize your data: A python tutorial](https://towardsdatascience.com/how-and-why-to-standardize-your-data-996926c2c832?source=friends_link&sk=54480b89c4ca00d80965d77b3baf8d7e)

---

## **Example with code**

```
from sklearn.preprocessing import StandardScaler
import numpy as np

# 4 samples/observations and 2 variables/features
data = np.array([[0, 0], [1, 0], [0, 1], [1, 1]])
scaler = StandardScaler()
scaled_data = scaler.fit_transform(data)

print(data)
[[0, 0],
 [1, 0],
 [0, 1],
 [1, 1]])

print(scaled_data)
[[-1. -1.]
 [ 1. -1.]
 [-1.  1.]
 [ 1.  1.]]
```

**Verify that the mean of each feature (column) is 0:**

```
scaled_data.mean(axis = 0)
array([0., 0.])
```

**Verify that the std of each feature (column) is 1:**

```
scaled_data.std(axis = 0)
array([1., 1.])
```

---

## Appendix: **The maths**

[image]

---

**UPDATE 08/2020**: Concerning the input parameters `with_mean` and `with_std` to `False`/`True`, I have provided an answer here: [StandardScaler difference between “with_std=False or True” and “with_mean=False or True”](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57381708/5025009)

Comment: Do you have any idea why I get `[1.15, 1.15]` when I compute as a pandas df: `pd.DataFrame(scaled_data).std(0)`?

Comment: when I run `pd.DataFrame(scaled_data)[0]` I get a series with `Name: 0, dtype: float64` and values `[-1.0, 1.0, -1.0, 1.0]`. Sorry for the formatting

Comment: @seralouk I liked you answer, however I am still wondering what is the intention behind transforming input data using `StandardScaler`, does it make the machine learning algorithm go faster, or helps making more accurate decisions, or something else?

Comment: Standardization of a dataset is a common requirement for many machine learning estimators: they might behave badly if the individual features do not more or less look like standard normally distributed data (e.g. Gaussian with 0 mean and unit variance).
For instance many elements used in the objective function of a learning algorithm (such as the RBF kernel of SVM or the L1 and L2 regularizers of linear models) assume that all features are centered around 0 and have variance in the same order.

Comment: So, Standardization leads to a) more stable b) less influenced by the range of variables c) faster fitting d) more stable performance

Comment: see also: https://towardsdatascience.com/how-and-why-to-standardize-your-data-996926c2c832?source=friends_link&sk=54480b89c4ca00d80965d77b3baf8d7e

Comment: I went through full SVM math and I didn't  see any assumptions that require input data should be standardized ( zero mean and unit power). On the other side, according to my experience, indeed standardized inputs are classified with a better accuracy about 2-3% in SVM. The reason is still not clear to me.

Comment: @MehmetFide 2 main reasons below:
1. SVMs are sensitive to the scale of the features because they try to find the optimal hyperplane that maximizes the margin between classes. If one feature has a much larger scale than another, it dominates the objective function. Standardization mitigates this issue by giving equal weight to all features.

2. Kernel-based SVMs: The kernel's ability to capture the similarity between points can be distorted if one feature is on a much larger scale. Standardization ensures that each feature contributes equally to the distance calculations

Answer (score 39):

StandardScaler performs the task of **Standardization**. Usually a dataset contains variables that are different in scale. For e.g. an Employee dataset will contain AGE column with values **on scale 20-70** and SALARY column with values **on scale 10000-80000**.
 As these two columns are different in scale, they are Standardized to have common scale while building machine learning model.

Comment: Best Easy Answer to Understand! thanks. Can you explain the process even more?

Answer (score 31):

How to calculate it:

[image]

You can read more here:

- http://sebastianraschka.com/Articles/2014_about_feature_scaling.html#standardization-and-min-max-scaling

Answer (score 12):

This is useful when you want to compare data that correspond to different units. In that case, you want to remove the units. To do that in a consistent way of all the data, you transform the data in a way that the variance is unitary and that the mean of the series is 0.

Comment: can u pls explain with an example..as in how it helps?..that wud be really helpful..thanks

Answer (score 11):

Following is a simple working example to explain how standarization calculation works. The theory part is already well explained in other answers.

```
>>>import numpy as np
>>>data = [[6, 2], [4, 2], [6, 4], [8, 2]]
>>>a = np.array(data)

>>>np.std(a, axis=0)
array([1.41421356, 0.8660254 ])

>>>np.mean(a, axis=0)
array([6. , 2.5])

>>>from sklearn.preprocessing import StandardScaler
>>>scaler = StandardScaler()
>>>scaler.fit(data)
>>>print(scaler.mean_)

#Xchanged = (X−μ)/σ  WHERE σ is Standard Deviation and μ is mean
>>>z=scaler.transform(data)
>>>z
```

**Calculation**

As you can see in the output, mean is [6. , 2.5] and std deviation is [1.41421356, 0.8660254 ]

Data is (0,1) position is 2
Standardization = (2 - 2.5)/0.8660254 = -0.57735027

Data in (1,0) position is 4
Standardization = (4-6)/1.41421356 = -1.414

**Result After Standardization**

[image]

**Check Mean and Std Deviation After Standardization**

[image]

Note: -2.77555756e-17 is very close to 0.

**References**

1. [Compare the effect of different scalers on data with outliers](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/auto_examples/preprocessing/plot_all_scaling.html)
2. [What's the difference between Normalization and Standardization?](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/10289/whats-the-difference-between-normalization-and-standardization)
3. [Mean of data scaled with sklearn StandardScaler is not zero](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40405803/mean-of-data-scaled-with-sklearn-standardscaler-is-not-zero)

Answer (score 4):

The answers above are great, but I needed a simple example to alleviate some concerns that I have had in the past. I wanted to make sure it was indeed treating each column separately. I am now reassured and can't find what example had caused me concern. All columns ***ARE*** scaled separately as described by those above.

#### CODE

```
import pandas as pd
import scipy.stats as ss
from sklearn.preprocessing import StandardScaler


data= [[1, 1, 1, 1, 1],[2, 5, 10, 50, 100],[3, 10, 20, 150, 200],[4, 15, 40, 200, 300]]

df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns=['N0', 'N1', 'N2', 'N3', 'N4']).astype('float64')

sc_X = StandardScaler()
df = sc_X.fit_transform(df)

num_cols = len(df[0,:])
for i in range(num_cols):
    col = df[:,i]
    col_stats = ss.describe(col)
    print(col_stats)
```

### OUTPUT

```
DescribeResult(nobs=4, minmax=(-1.3416407864998738, 1.3416407864998738), mean=0.0, variance=1.3333333333333333, skewness=0.0, kurtosis=-1.3599999999999999)
DescribeResult(nobs=4, minmax=(-1.2828087129930659, 1.3778315806221817), mean=-5.551115123125783e-17, variance=1.3333333333333337, skewness=0.11003776770595125, kurtosis=-1.394993095506219)
DescribeResult(nobs=4, minmax=(-1.155344148338584, 1.53471088361394), mean=0.0, variance=1.3333333333333333, skewness=0.48089217736510326, kurtosis=-1.1471008824318165)
DescribeResult(nobs=4, minmax=(-1.2604572012883055, 1.2668071116222517), mean=-5.551115123125783e-17, variance=1.3333333333333333, skewness=0.0056842140599118185, kurtosis=-1.6438177182479734)
DescribeResult(nobs=4, minmax=(-1.338945389819976, 1.3434309690153527), mean=5.551115123125783e-17, variance=1.3333333333333333, skewness=0.005374558840039456, kurtosis=-1.3619131970819205)
```

## NOTE:

The scipy.stats module is correctly reporting the "sample" variance, which uses (n - 1) in the denominator. The "population" variance would use n in the denominator for the calculation of variance. To understand better, please see the code below that uses scaled data from the first column of the data set above:

### Code

```
import scipy.stats as ss

sc_Data = [[-1.34164079], [-0.4472136], [0.4472136], [1.34164079]]
col_stats = ss.describe([-1.34164079, -0.4472136, 0.4472136, 1.34164079])
print(col_stats)
print()

mean_by_hand = 0
for row in sc_Data:
    for element in row:
        mean_by_hand += element
mean_by_hand /= 4

variance_by_hand = 0
for row in sc_Data:
    for element in row:
        variance_by_hand += (mean_by_hand - element)**2
sample_variance_by_hand = variance_by_hand / 3
sample_std_dev_by_hand = sample_variance_by_hand ** 0.5

pop_variance_by_hand = variance_by_hand / 4
pop_std_dev_by_hand = pop_variance_by_hand ** 0.5

print("Sample of Population Calcs:")
print(mean_by_hand, sample_variance_by_hand, sample_std_dev_by_hand, '\n')
print("Population Calcs:")
print(mean_by_hand, pop_variance_by_hand, pop_std_dev_by_hand)
```

### Output

```
DescribeResult(nobs=4, minmax=(-1.34164079, 1.34164079), mean=0.0, variance=1.3333333422778562, skewness=0.0, kurtosis=-1.36000000429325)

Sample of Population Calcs:
0.0 1.3333333422778562 1.1547005422523435

Population Calcs:
0.0 1.000000006708392 1.000000003354196
```

Comment: Why variance is not 1, please?

Comment: @Max, scipy stats is using sample variance. See new additions to answer.

Comment: @seralouk Yes if the population variance and std deviation, but not for the sample variance and std deviation - scipy stats defaulting to the sample calcs.

Answer (score 3):

After applying `StandardScaler()`, **each column** in X will have mean of 0 and standard deviation of 1.

Formulas are listed by others on this page.

Rationale: some algorithms require data to look like this (see [sklearn docs](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.preprocessing.StandardScaler.html)).

Comment: Correct. Some answers showing the scipy stats description of the scaled data's sample mean and variance. Sample variance for small data sets can be significantly different from population variance.

Answer (score 2):

We apply `StandardScalar()` on a row basis.

So, for each row in a column (I am assuming that you are working with a Pandas DataFrame):

```
x_new = (x_original - mean_of_distribution) / std_of_distribution
```

Few points -

1. It is called Standard Scalar as we are dividing it by the standard deviation of the distribution (distr. of the feature). Similarly, you can guess for `MinMaxScalar()`.
2. The original distribution remains the same after applying `StandardScalar()`. It is a common misconception that the distribution gets changed to a Normal Distribution. We are just squashing the range into [0, 1].