# StandardScaler difference between "with_std=False or True" and "with_mean=False or True"

Tags: python, scikit-learn, pca, decomposition

I am trying to standardize some data to be able to apply PCA to it. I am using sklearn.preprocessing.StandardScaler. I am having trouble to understand the difference between using `True` or `False` in the parameters `with_mean` and `with_std` ([documentation](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.preprocessing.StandardScaler.html)).

Can someone give a more extended explanation?

Comment: If you set `with_mean`/`with_std` to `False`, it means it will use `0`/`1` as mean/std dev instead of measuring these on the data first. If both are thus set to `False`, you use a [*standard normal distribution*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Normal_distribution#Standard_normal_distribution).

Answer (score 5):

I have provided more details in [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50879522/5025009), but let me just explain this here as well.

The standardation of the data (each column/feature/variable indivivually) involves the following equations:

[image]

---

**Explanation:**

If you set `with_mean` and `with_std` to `False`, then the mean `μ` is set to `0` and the `std` to 1, assuming that the columns/features are coming from the normal gaussian distribution (which has 0 mean and 1 std).

If you set `with_mean` and `with_std` to `True`, then you will actually use the true `μ` and `σ` of your data. This is the most common approach.

Comment: Hi, could you please include an example with the answer showing the difference between with_mean and with_std set to False/True? It will help me in clearing my understanding further. I am sorry for the trouble.

Answer (score 3):

A standard scaler is usually used to fit a [*normal distribution*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Normal_distribution) with the data, and then calculate the [*Z-scores*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Standard_score). This thus means that first the *mean μ* and *standard deviation σ* of the data are calculated, and then the *Z-scores* are calculated with *z = (x - μ) / σ*.

By setting `with_mean` or `with_std` to `False`, we respectively set the mean μ to `0` and the standard deviation σ to 1. If both are set to `False`, we thus calculate the Z-score of a [*standard normal distribution* [wiki]](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Normal_distribution#Standard_normal_distribution).

The main use case of setting `with_mean` to `False` is processing *sparse* matrices. Sparse matrices contain a significant amount of zeros, and are therefore stored in a way that the zeros usually use no (or very little) memory. If we would fit the mean, and then calculate the z-score, it is almost certain that all zeros will be mapped to non-zero values, and thus use (significant amounts of) memory. For large sparse matrices, that can result in a *memory error*: the data is that large, that the memory is not able to store the matrix anymore. By setting *μ=0*, this means that values that are zero, will map on zero. The result of the standard scaler is a sparse matrix with the same shape.