# Correctly scaling features for machine learning

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn, logistic-regression

My dataframe contains three kinds of features:

1. features with observations ranging from 0 to 100
2. features with observations coded as 0 or 1 (0 meaning no, 1 being yes)
3. Features with observations ranging from 1 to 5 (A persons response to a question with 1 being strongly disagree and 5 being strongly agree)

Can I just apply `StandardScaler` to my dataframe and all the features will be scaled correctly? or is there a specific scaling method required for each of the different kinds of features in my dataframe?

Comment: Well, that's a point of view; another is that of teaching one how to fish instead of just giving them one single fish for today (and keep them dependable)... BTW, I have essentially provided you with the answer, in case you were too busy with the rhetorics to notice.

Answer (score 0):

`StandardScaler` scales your data so that each column will have μ = 0 and σ = 1. According to the [documentation](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.preprocessing.StandardScaler.html):

> Centering and scaling happen independently on each feature by
> computing the relevant statistics on the samples in the training set.

As each feature is scaled independently of the other(s), their relevant magnitude  difference does not over-shadow each other. It is worth noting that the scaling depends heavily on distribution of training samples for each feature. A standard normally distributed training data will result in perfect scaling. For further understanding you may go through the [documentation](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.preprocessing.StandardScaler.html) and also see [this SO thread](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50879522/13085345).

Sample data is scaled in the following code:

```
from sklearn.preprocessing import StandardScaler
import numpy as np

data = np.array([[100, 0, 2], [66, 1, 5], [50, 0, 4], [33, 1, 1], [0, 0, 3], [25, 0, 2], [75, 1, 4], [50, 1, 3]])

scaler = StandardScaler()
scaled_data = scaler.fit_transform(data)

print ("Scaled Array:")
print(scaled_data)

print('Mean :', scaled_data.mean(axis=0))
print('Standard Deviation :', scaled_data.std(axis=0))
print('Variance :', scaled_data.var(axis=0))
```

The output is:

```
Scaled Array:
[[ 1.71992157 -1.         -0.81649658]
 [ 0.55329148  1.          1.63299316]
 [ 0.00428908 -1.          0.81649658]
 [-0.57902597  1.         -1.63299316]
 [-1.71134341 -1.          0.        ]
 [-0.85352716 -1.         -0.81649658]
 [ 0.86210533  1.          0.81649658]
 [ 0.00428908  1.          0.        ]]
Mean : [3.46944695e-18 0.00000000e+00 0.00000000e+00]
Standard Deviation : [1. 1. 1.]
Variance : [1. 1. 1.]
```